# React Native: Change text colour in Paper Button

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I am relatively new in react native.

I can easily show button (with shadow, etc) as in here.

```
 <Button
  mode="contained"
  color={'#f08e25'}
  contentStyle={{ height: 44 }}
  onPress={this.onPressSubmit}
  theme={theme} >SUBMIT </Button>
```

I am also referring to this document.

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html#contentStyle

Problem is I can't change text colour if mode is "contained". I tried in contentStyle or theme and it is not working. How shall I change text color if mode is "contained"?

Comment: When change to contained color property is mean background color. Simple way try <button><text style={{color:'yourvalue}} ></text></button>

Comment: oh..it worked! thank you. may be we shall move to answer.

Comment: I'm happy to be helped to you :)

Comment: @NijatAliyev is possible to change colour of 'outlined' button in 'paper button'

Comment: The latest documentation lives at https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/Button/#style and has quite a nice table that shows what theme properties you need to set to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 18):

For `mode="contained"` react-native-paper buttons, `color` changes the background colour and you need `labelStyle` to change the text. For `mode="flat"` buttons, `color` will change the text.
You just need to add the `labelStyle` prop. The code below will give you your orange button with white text for example:

```
<Button
  mode="contained"
  color="#f08e25"
  contentStyle={{ height: 44 }}
  labelStyle={{ color: "white", fontSize: 18 }}
  onPress={this.onPressSubmit}
  theme={theme} >
    SUBMIT 
</Button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do  it theme wise? i.e. if you want all the buttons to have labelStyle color set as white.

Answer (score 4):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button,Text } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <Button icon="camera" color="blue" dark={true} compact={true}  style={{color:"red",marginTop:100}} mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
   <Text style={{color:"red"}}>press me</Text>
  </Button>
);

export default MyComponent;
```

this is your answer
in contained mode , color is shows for the color of all button not just text

Comment: is it possible to change colour border in 'outlined button'

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressSubmit = () => {
    setState({flag:true})
}
<Button
  mode="contained"
  color={'#f08e25'}
  contentStyle={this.state.flag ? styleA : styleB}
  onPress={this.onPressSubmit}
  theme={theme} >SUBMIT </Button>
```

Comment: Please add some more information regarding your answer, instead of just the code. This way it is easier to understand for everyone :)